# How to change date parameter value depends on another date parameter value in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have one date parameter which will be change by user. From that date parameter i have to calculate local timezone show in another date parameter.

I have used second parameter date in data set query to filter data. I am not getting how to reflect change of date from first parameter into second parameter in SSRS report.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm. You want to select a date in first date parameter, and your second date parameter should automatically select that date but (for example) 5 hours later?

Comment: Yes.It will convert in UTC local time.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps to get the second parameter use the calculation based on first parameter

In the 2nd parameter Properties -->Available values-->Specify values--> ADD
-->Click on `fx` in label and value and from category you will be able to select your parameter--> double click on the 1st date parameter and you can type in the calculation you need for the 2nd parameter.